# Android: resource style/Theme.MaterialComponents not found

Tags: android, flutter

I am developing a flutter project. I am trying to use a descendant of Theme.AppCompat for my activity. Below is my code.

**/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.
         
         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**/android/app/src/main/res/values-night/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is on -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.
         
         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**/android/app/build.gradle**

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }
    
    def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
        throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
    }
    
    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }
    
    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }
    
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    
    def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
       def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
       if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
           keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
       }
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 31
    
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
            minSdkVersion 23
            targetSdkVersion 30
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
        }
    
        signingConfigs {
           release {
               keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
               keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
               storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
               storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
           }
       }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                minifyEnabled false
                shrinkResources false
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    }
    
    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.2'
}
```

When I run my code, I get the following error.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.MaterialComponents (aka com.peresiaapp.peresia_customer:style/Theme.MaterialComponents) not found.
     error: resource style/Theme.MaterialComponents (aka com.peresiaapp.peresia_customer:style/Theme.MaterialComponents) not found.
     error: failed linking references.
```

What went wrong here?

Comment: from document https://m2.material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started, could you try add implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>' to dependencies

Comment: @chunhunghan: Please provide this as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your confirm. I have added this as an answer.

Comment: @PeakGen does this answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 3):

From document https://m2.material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started 
Material Components for Android is available through Google's Maven Repository. To use it: 
...
Step 3: Add the library to the dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
    // ...
  }
```